# Form parent children structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, javascript-objects

I have an array as below.The length of the list may vary. Here based on the case,sr and func keys we need to form parent-child dictionary.

```
[
 {
   "case": "CS0181582",
   "sr": "SR0025382",
   "func": "FLT003",
   "kpi": "su_ping",
   "origin": "bstn_switch",
   "value": "false",
   "status": "UP"
 },
 {
   "case": "CS0181582",
   "sr": "SR0025382",
   "func": "FLT003",
   "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
   "origin": "su_stats",
   "value": "180000",
   "status": "UP"
 },
 {
   "case": "CS0181583",
   "sr": "SR0025383",
   "func": "FLT004",
   "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
   "origin": "su_stats",
   "value": "180000",
   "status": "UP"
 }
]
```

The expected output is,

```
{
 "case": "CS0181582",
 "sr": "SR0025382",
 "func": "FLT003",
 "KPI": {
    "kpi": "su_ping",
    "origin": "bstn_switch",
    "value": "false",
    "status": "UP"
  },
  "KPI": {
    "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
    "origin": "su_stats",
    "value": "180000",
    "status": "UP"
  },
  "case": "CS0181583",
  "sr": "SR0025383",
  "func": "FLT004",
  "KPI": {
    "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
    "origin": "su_stats",
    "value": "180000",
    "status": "UP"
   }
}
```

Using Javascript I need to get this output..Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: This is [not a programming question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: also, technical terminology: JS doesn't have "dictionaries", you're thinking of Python. In JS, the data you're showing is called an array of plain objects.

Comment: ... and the expected result is impossible (it contains doubled keys).

Comment: You could get for `KPI` an array which contains all KPIs inside but you can't have in the object multiple keys with same name KPI

Comment: Sorry I will edit this post

Answer (score 1):

You can't get for **KPI** an array which contains all KPIs inside but you can have in the object multiple keys with same name KPI. I suppose you wanted a solution like this.Here an example for the new **KPI**-entry:

```
"KPI": [
      {
        "kpi": "su_ping",
        "origin": "bstn_switch",
        "value": "bstn_switch"
      },
      {
        "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
        "origin": "su_stats",
        "value": "su_stats"
      }
    ]
```

Go with forEach through your dictionary and look in a n indexResult-array if there is an entry for a string which consist out of your 3 keys with delimiter "#" (you could use any other char). If not create a new entry in your result-array and create this entry. Otherwise take with this index the entry in your result-array and add here the next KPI to it.

```js
function convertDict(dict) {
    result = [];
    indexResult = [];
    dict.forEach(elem => {
    let kpi = {kpi: elem.kpi, origin: elem.origin, value: elem.origin};
        let ind = elem.case+'#'+elem.sr+'#'+elem.func;
          index = indexResult.indexOf(ind);
        if (index==-1) {
            result.push( {case: elem.case, sr: elem.sr, func: elem.func, KPI: [kpi]});
          indexResult.push(ind);
        } else {
            result[index].KPI = result[index].KPI.concat(kpi);
        }
        
    });
    return result;
}

let dict = [
 {
   "case": "CS0181582",
   "sr": "SR0025382",
   "func": "FLT003",
   "kpi": "su_ping",
   "origin": "bstn_switch",
   "value": "false",
   "status": "UP"
 },
 {
   "case": "CS0181582",
   "sr": "SR0025382",
   "func": "FLT003",
   "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
   "origin": "su_stats",
   "value": "180000",
   "status": "UP"
 },
 {
   "case": "CS0181583",
   "sr": "SR0025383",
   "func": "FLT004",
   "kpi": "outgoing_traffic_limit",
   "origin": "su_stats",
   "value": "180000",
   "status": "UP"
 }
];

console.log(convertDict(dict));
```

Comment: Thank you so much..This is the  output I needed

Comment: Glad to help you. If you are satisfied you could accept the answer.